# Add "tab statusbar to scroll to top" to a UITableView contained in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` that contains some `UITableViews`. Now if I tap the status bar of my phone, the usual behavior would be that the visible tableView would scroll to the top. As it's contained in my scrollView, it's not doing that.

Neither the scrollView nor the tableView get any callbacks from the system. I was hoping the `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:` would be called on my containing scrollView so that I can trigger that behavior on my tableViews myself, but it's not.

Any ideas? Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but I'm having trouble imagining in what situation one would need to embed table views in a scroll view.

Comment: @Guillaume Algis It's unusual but it occurs in the native stocks app on iOS

Comment: Have you set the delegates for the scrollView and tableView?

Comment: if you have a scrollview contained in a scrollview you should set scrollsToTop = No on the one that shouldn't scroll.

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis it's a bit like the new twitter app does. TableViews that you can swipe through...

Comment: @Caro , can you post your answer as an actual answer, then I will check it as correct. I completely oversaw that there was an other scrollview that also needed the `scrollsToTop` set to NO. Dumb me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a scrollview that contains another scrollview none of them will get the scrollToTop event. You got to set one of the scrollviews to scrollsToTop = No in order for the other one to work.